# currentArray.forEach is not a function (Fetch API)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I'm trying to query a URL string and pull in some weather data. I'm getting the response but for some reason, I'm not able to pull in the data. I'm getting an error saying cur

```js
const weatherForm = document.querySelector("#weather-form");
weatherForm.addEventListener("submit", fetchWeather);

function fetchWeather(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const searchTerm = document.querySelector(".search").value;
  fetch(`https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=c54944da22b147b48ec152033160205&q=${searchTerm}`)
  .then((response) => {return response.json(); })
  .then((resp => {
   // console.log(resp);
    let currentArray = resp.current;
    console.log(currentArray);
    showWeather(currentArray);
  }))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function showWeather(currentArray) {
  alert("Hello");
  const results = document.querySelector(".results");
  
  let output = '<div class="container">';
  currentArray.forEach((weatherData => {
    output += `
    <h2>${weatherData.feelslike_f}</h2>
`;
  }))
  document.querySelector(".results").innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<form id="weather-form">
  <input type="text" class="search">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<div class="results"></div>
```

rentArray.forEach is not a function. Here is my code: 
I think it has something to do with the way I'm doing `let currentArray = resp.current` but I'm not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is a link to my codepen if you would like to take a better look.

https://codepen.io/Brushel/pen/JBGGYp?editors=1011

Comment: `resp.current` is an object not an array, look at the structure of the JSON. `{ }` denotes an object, `[ ]` denotes array

Comment: `resp.current` is an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API is only returning a single object, not an array of objects. Fix `showWeather` so that it only accesses the property of the object, rather than try to iterate over an array:

```js
const weatherForm = document.querySelector("#weather-form");
weatherForm.addEventListener("submit", fetchWeather);

function fetchWeather(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const searchTerm = document.querySelector(".search").value;
  fetch(`https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=c54944da22b147b48ec152033160205&q=${searchTerm}`)
  .then((response) => {return response.json(); })
  .then((resp => {
   // console.log(resp);
    let currentArray = resp.current;
    // console.log(currentArray);
    showWeather(currentArray);
  }))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function showWeather(weatherData) {
  document.querySelector(".results").innerHTML = `
  <div class="container">
    <h2>${weatherData.feelslike_f}</h2>
  </div>
  `;
}
```

```html
<form id="weather-form">
  <input type="text" class="search">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<div class="results"></div>
```